# Jest TS client mock instantiation returning array of undefined elements and not the mocked resolved value

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am currently writing tests for a helper function that I wrote which takes a client and array. Basically a site has many tasks and I want to get all tasks for all sites. (Method works fine)

```
export async function getAllTasks(
  sites: Site[],
  client: Client
): Promise<Task[]> {
  try {
    return (
      await Promise.all(
        sites.map(async (site) => {
          return client.getTasks(site.id);
        })
      )
    ).flat();
  } catch (e) {
    throw new createError(400, 'Bad Request: Unable to get all site tasks');
  }
}
```

```
jest.mock('@src/client');
const mockClient = <jest.Mock<Client>>Client;

describe('Helpers', () => {
  const mockTask = createMock<Task>();

  mockClient.mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      getTasks: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([mockTask]),
      ...mockClient.prototype
    };
  });

  it('getAllTasks()', async () => {
    const mockSites = [createMock<Site>()];
    const mockClient = new mockClient({
      // constructor params here
    });
    const tasks = await getAllTasks(mockSites, mockClient);
    expect(tasks).toEqual([mockTask]);
  });
});
```

The test fails with the following:

```
 expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 5
    + Received  + 1

      Array [
    -   Object {
    -     "customerId": 0,
    -     "id": "",
    -     "siteId": "",
    -   },
    +   undefined,
      ]
```

Basically the mocked method is returning an array of one undefined element and the test fails. I feel like the reason this is happening is pretty subtle, but I can't figure out the root cause. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Im a dinugs, my implementation restructuring was backwards. Here's the corrected form for any referencers.

```
mockClient.mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      ...mockClient.prototype
      getTasks: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([mockTask])
    };
  });
```